# Convert postgresql query to SQL Server 2016 by using json

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my postgresql code:

```
SELECT 
    ARRAY_TO_JSON(ARRAY_AGG(ROW_TO_JSON(A)))  AS "paymentsinfo"
FROM
    (SELECT
         customerid,
         (SELECT (ROW_TO_JSON(d))  AS "customerinfo"
          FROM
              (SELECT info.id, firstname, lastname, middlename
               FROM users info 
               WHERE info.userid = payments.customerid) d)
    FROM payments
```

I want to convert this code to SQL Server 2016 query using open json.

Here is my sample output:

```
[{"customerdetails":{"middlename":null, "lastname":"test", "id":12, "firstname":"customer1"}, "id":10, "customerid":12}]
```

Comment: Hello i think thoses Ms documentation can help you :) 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If you can post sample off data and result and we trying to get same with using SQL Server.

Comment: Hi @Adams have you some sample data please ? we're going to try to share a answer.

Comment: @pascal sanchez:  i have provided the sample output

Comment: thank you. Have you table row for trying reproduce the same :). Thnak you in advance. @Adams

Comment: i have tried different ways but cannot get the above output. can you help me out.  Thank You in advance :) @pascal sanchez

Comment: Thank you for update i have a result with mock table on answer please let me know if your're able to reproduce this with you table and data other solution put the table format and some data as example :).

Comment: I put some edit on answer to reproduce your expected output

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you can use the next query :

```
create Table #usersTable
(
    Id int,
    firstname varchar(128) 
)

Insert into #usersTable
(
    Id,
    firstname
)
SELECT 1,'Test'
UNION
SELECT 2, 'Test Bis'


create Table #paymentsInfoTable
(
    Id int,
    usersId int,
    MockValue varchar(128) 
)


Insert into #paymentsInfoTable
(
    Id,
    usersId,
    MockValue
)
SELECT 1,1,'Payments 00001110000 00001'
UNION
SELECT 2,1,'Payments 00001110000 00002'
UNION
SELECT 3,1,'Payments 00001110000 00003'
UNION
SELECT 4,2,'Payments 00001110000 00003'


SELECT TP.Id AS [Payment.Number], TP.usersId AS [Payment.User], TP.MockValue AS [Payment.Information], 
    TU.*
FROM #usersTable AS TU
JOIN  #paymentsInfoTable AS TP ON TU.Id = TP.usersId
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Payments')




    DROP TABLE  #usersTable


    DROP TABLE  #paymentsInfoTable
```

For more information about MsSQL Server and JSON you can see :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

EDIT : To reproduce your expected result ==>

```
    create Table #usersTable
(
    Id int,
    firstname varchar(128),
    lastname varchar(128),
    middlename varchar(128)
)

Insert into #usersTable
(
    Id,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    middlename
)
SELECT 1,'customer1','test',null
UNION
SELECT 2, 'customer2', 'test2', 'middlename'


create Table #paymentsInfoTable
(
    Id int,
    usersId int,
    PaymentsOtherFields varchar(128) 
)


Insert into #paymentsInfoTable
(
    Id,
    usersId,
    PaymentsOtherFields
)
SELECT 1,1,'Payments 00001110000 00001'
UNION
SELECT 2,1,'Payments 00001110000 00002'
UNION
SELECT 3,1,'Payments 00001110000 00003'
UNION
SELECT 4,2,'Payments 00001110000 00003'


SELECT TU.Id AS [customerdetail.id], TU.firstname AS [customerdetail.firstname], TU.lastname AS [customerdetail.lastname], ISNULL(TU.middlename,'') AS [customerdetail.middlename],
    TP.Id AS 'id', TP.usersId AS 'customerid', TP.PaymentsOtherFields AS 'PaymentInformationAddFields'
FROM #usersTable AS TU
JOIN  #paymentsInfoTable AS TP ON TU.Id = TP.usersId
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('customerdetails')




    DROP TABLE  #usersTable


    DROP TABLE  #paymentsInfoTable
```

The result was :

```
{"customerdetails":[{"customerdetail":{"id":1,"firstname":"customer1","lastname":"test","middlename":""},"id":1,"customerid":1,"PaymentInformationAddFields":"Payments 00001110000 00001"},{"customerdetail":{"id":1,"firstname":"customer1","lastname":"test","middlename":""},"id":2,"customerid":1,"PaymentInformationAddFields":"Payments 00001110000 00002"},{"customerdetail":{"id":1,"firstname":"customer1","lastname":"test","middlename":""},"id":3,"customerid":1,"PaymentInformationAddFields":"Payments 00001110000 00003"},{"customerdetail":{"id":2,"firstname":"customer2","lastname":"test2","middlename":"middlename"},"id":4,"customerid":2,"PaymentInformationAddFields":"Payments 00001110000 00003"}]}
```

Comment: @Adams hy, have you find way to do this ? thank in advance.

Comment: @adams the relevant example can be easily convert to work with your table. Post your full structure database (for 2 table) or send my a dump off your database and i'm going to convert your query if have time. Sincerely, Pascal.